# VB.NET & MySQL : DataGrid error displaying MonthName

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Having trouble displaying MonthName in a DataGridView from data in MySQL

**Query:**

```
SELECT ItemName, Description, PurchaseDate, MONTHNAME(PurchaseDate) AS PurchaseMonth FROM tblItems
```

**Error:**

> System.ArguementException:Parameter is not valid

Displaying the month number, using `MONTH(PurchaseDate)` works perfect but when I try to show the month name I get a datagrid error. When I run the SQL in MySQL it returns the expected results.

When I add in a DataError event it just shows a red exclimation mark in the fields where `MONTHNAME(PurchaseDate)` should be.

Comment: Is the cell of that grid defined to accept only INT values?

Comment: Nope, tried in the vb code to print the string 'PurchaseMonth' into the cells and it displayed fine

Comment: Are you using a strongly-typed `DataTable`/`TableAdapter`?

Comment: Dim daItems As New OdbcDataAdapter ... Dim dsItems As New DataSet ... 
Dim dtItems As New DataTable

Ive also adjusted the query to put other colums (which contain strings) into that field and it works fine. Just seems to be a problem with MonthName

Comment: Just upvoted BigYellowCactus' comment - if that column in the Grid isn't expecting a string versus an int, that's your problem.

Comment: Column can take strings no problem, error only happens when the sql statement contains MonthName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. 
Even though MonthName(PurchaseDate) worked when run directly against the database, I had to use Cast in the SQL string when passing in from VB.NET

Amended SQL:

```
SELECT ItemName, Description, PurchaseDate, CAST(MONTHNAME(PurchaseDate) AS CHAR) AS PurchaseMonth FROM tblItems
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do that?

Just load the raw date and use format string to get the name

```
dim purchaseDate as DateTime = DateTime.Now

dim purchaseMonth as String = purchaseDate.Format("MMMM")
' or
dim purchaseMonth as String = String.Format("{0}", purchasDate")
```

Databindings also support formatting.

This method has the advantage, that it respects the locals from the users environment:

```
' english: July
' german:  Juli
```

Comment: I was trying to populate the grid directly from a dataset

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you can just bind the dataset to your grid and set the `Format` for the column (in the grid, not the datatable) to "MMMM". Not sure if you are using WinForms or ASP.NET but it should be something like `datagrid.Columns("PurchaseDate").DefaultCellStyle.Format = "MMMM"`